# 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions (pythonanywhere)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pythonanywhere

I am trying to schedule my script on pythonanywhere with a beginner account.
Here is my code

```
class SeeTicket(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self ,driver_path='/home/saifbyte/seetickets/chromedriver.exe', teardown = False):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        options.add_experimental_option( 'excludeSwitches' , ['enable-logging'])
        options = options
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        self.teardown = teardown
        super(SeeTicket , self).__init__(options = options  , executable_path=self.driver_path)


        self.maximize_window()
```

but when I am scheduling this task , i get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

whole traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/saifbyte/seetickets/chromedriver.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/saifbyte/seetickets/seeticket_script.py", line 3, in <module>
    st = SeeTicket()
  File "/home/saifbyte/seetickets/Scrapers/seeticket.py", line 20, in __init__
    super(SeeTicket , self).__init__(options = options  , executable_path=self.driver_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

My executable path is correct but still getting error.

Alternatively are there any good alternative to pythonanywhere.

Thanks

Comment: PythonAnywhere is a Linux environment so you can't run Windows executables there.  Also -- there's a chromedriver installed, so you should be able to run selenium code without uploading one.  There's a caveat though: if you're on a free account, you will not be able to scrape, since free accounts have restricted internet access on PythonAnywhere.

Comment: Also, take a look at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium

Answer (score -1):

From the *Traceback* I observe a linux styled path:

```
/home/saifbyte/seetickets/...
```

Presumably an non [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) system.

---

### Solution

You need to drop the extension of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) binary executable. Your effective line of code will be:

```
def __init__(self ,driver_path='/home/saifbyte/seetickets/chromedriver', teardown = False):
```